# Listing view will not filter based on captured URL value

Tags: python, django

With a given URL path, there is a variable portion that dictates which model instances are displayed depending on whatever uppercase letter is contained within it. As shown, the letter 'A' is set as the default for the view.

However, if any other letter is passed to the path (such as 'B', "C", ...), the QuerySet is not filtered to what should be only those instances whose first letter matches that variable captured value.

What can be done so that any letter from A-Z will return the correct QuerySet. As of now, any uppercase letter returns only a QuerySet where each model instances' first letter begins with 'A'.

```
# urls.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, re_path, include
from minerals import views


mineral_patterns = ([
    re_path("", views.filter_letter_list, name="letter_list"),
    re_path('(?P<query>([A-Z]))/', views.filter_letter_list, name="letter_list"),
], "minerals")

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include(mineral_patterns))
]
```

```
# views.py

from random import choice
from string import ascii_uppercase

from django.shortcuts import render, get_list_or_404
from .models import Mineral

def filter_letter_list(request, query="A"):
    # import pdb; pdb.set_trace();
    minerals = get_list_or_404(Mineral, name__startswith=query)
    random_mineral = choice(Mineral.objects.all())
    return render(
        request, 
        "minerals/list.html", 
        context={
            'minerals': minerals,
            'random_mineral': random_mineral,
            'query': query,
            'letters': ascii_uppercase
        }
    )
```

Comment: instead of writing 2 paths why not just writing 1 path `'(?P<query>([A-Z]))/'`?  and check in the view if the parameter value exist or not in the view to return appropriate result

Answer (score 1):

Django looks for matches in the order you have specified the paths. Switch the order for the two `mineral_patterns` and it should work fine.

The first path matches every match for the second path as well, so your second path is never being called.